# Installing a non-default mouse driver in VMWare Workstation

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation, razer-mouse

VMWare Tools installs a generic "VMWare Pointing Device", and seems to "force" the guest to use that driver for the mouse.  When I install the specialized drivers for the mouse in the guest, it can't find a compatible mouse.

- Windows 7 x64 host/guest
- Workstation 9.02
- Razer Naga mouse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OS in the VM can not find your mouse since it has no Razer Naga hardware.

Basically the following happens:

All sorts of hardware, e.g.

```
mouse,   \                   Virtual machine    \
keyboard  |                  with hardware as   |  
CPU        }  host OS --->   defined by the     |  Guest OS recognising the 
Wifi.     |                  VM's configuration /  VM configured 'hardware'
...      /
```

The hardware on the host OS and the 'hardware' on the virtual OS do not need to match.

They are often the same for performance reasons (e.g. same CPU type), but they can be different.  In your case you host OS has a real Naga mouse. It can detect it. It can use it.  The VM is emulating a standard mouse. Software inside the VM can look all it wants for the Naga, but it will only find the virtual hardware of the VM and not the real hardware from the physical machine.

If you want to get access to the Naga in the guest, you will either need to:

1. Write part of the VM making it emulate a naga (which will then be an option even if you use another mouse on the physical system.
2. Or passthough raw access to the VM. Usually that excludes the hardware from the host OS. (So if you want to us the Naga in both the real host and with the VM you would need two Naga mice).

Note that this usually requires VT-d or AMD-Vi support in your CPU, and that this feature is mostly used to pass-though RAID cards and 10Gbit NICs rather then mere mice.)

---

[Update and correction]

It does not merely require AMD-Vi or VT-d; it requires:

1. A CPU with AMD-Vi or VT-d for the [I/O MMU virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization),
2. and a BIOS/OS which supports this.

Many laptops ship with a CPU which is capable of I/O MMU virtualization, but lack the support in the BIOS/UEFI. As a result you still can not use this feature.

It also seems that Vmware workstation has an option to do 'special things' with USB based devices. Since most current mice are USB based you should be able to go to the [VM] tab and select the devices under [Removeable devices]. That will also disconnect the USB based device from the host and connect it semi-directly to the VM.

[image: Screenshot of VMware workstation with the discussed menu options]